# How many pools per session for Cassandra Java Driver?

Tags: cassandra, driver, connection-pooling, datastax-java-driver

I was reading [this article](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/manual/pooling/) on Cassandra connection pooling, and it says:

> For each Session, there is one connection pool per connected host

But then it has the following diagram which shows 1-n on Session-Pool:

[image: connection objects ratios]
So, how many pools per session the driver manages after all? Is this customizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each session driver have one control & N data connections (configurable) **per connected host**. You can configure number of connections as described in documentation, potentially setting different number of connections for local & remote connections (if you're using DC-aware load balancing policy).

By default the number of data connections for V3 protocol is one - that's enough, especially if you increase the number of "in-flight" requests to high number (V3 allows to have up to 32k "in-flight" requests). If you combine high number of "in-flight" requests with async operations, you can reach quite high throughput, but you may need to take care that you won't issue too many requests. (I use [following class](https://github.com/alexott/datastax-bootcamp-project/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/bootcamp/SessionLimiter.java) to control it).